# Add Image to Grid - WPF

Tags: c#, image, grid

I am wondering how I could set an Image to "grid_Main", if I have created all my images in a loop (See Code).

Code:

```
private void MoleImageMaker()
{
    NumofImages = TUtils.GetIniInt(Moleini, "NumPictures", "pictures", 8);
    String MoleImageFunction = TUtils.GetIniFileString(Moleini, "ImagePath", "PictureFile", Root + "mole2.png");

    for (int i = 0; i < NumofImages; i++)
    {
        Image mole = new Image();
        mole.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(MoleImageFunction));
        mole.Name = "Mole" + i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Maybe if we share our tries and fails we can find out how to do it !?

Comment: lol sounds like a good idea.

Comment: I actually meant. What have you tried so far and where are you stuck ? I take it that if you are here asking this question you looked around and tried stuff ? I suppose this code isn't working ? Is there an error message ? An exception thrown ?  Where does it crash ? Where is the grid ?

Comment: Well, I just I am generally not sure on how to say "Put his image here" if I have made these images in a loop.

Comment: I am working in WPF :)

Comment: Just a normal Grid, made in the code.

Comment: How about to make Grid background with a BitmapBrush?

Comment: They also need to have the ability to have a click function.

Comment: then how about to put `Button` with BitmapBrush background inside of `Grid`.

Comment: You can handle the MouseLeftButtonUp event.. It can work as a "click"..

Comment: @ManolisXountasis Can you give me an example of a click event code, the way I am trying to do it now does not seem to work?

Comment: This is the .cs code 
'private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
//handle the code here.
}'
xaml:
' <Grid MouseLeftButtonUp="Grid_MouseLeftButtonUp">'

Comment: @ManolisXountasis Will this effect when the entire grid is clicked or just when the images are clicked?

Comment: The entire grid.
**EDIT** 
If you want to have many clickable images why not to use a ListBox? just an idea that i came through..

Comment: @ManolisXountasis How can I make it so that it will only effect if the image is clicked? I am sorry if I seem demanding, it's just that I am new to C#, and I have been working on this application for a long time, and I just want to get it done.

Comment: Check  my edit to previous comment. If it does not meet your requirements we will search for another workaround.

Comment: @ManolisXountasis Well, it seem easier to do it in a ListBox, but the program I have been writing needs to be done in mostly .cs code, and little to no XAML.

Comment: It's easy to add ListBoxItems in a ListBox. You will have the same loop with different elements. If you have to do it in a grid then you have to youe mathematics to recognize the exact click-point and calculate which image could be at this point. This means that you have to keep informations when you insert the images.. It's a little difficult.. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumofImages; i++)
{
  Image mole = new Image();
  mole.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(MoleImageFunction));
  mole.Name = "Mole" + i;  
  Grid.SetColumn(mole, i);
  grid_Main.Children.Add(mole);
}
```